# Show how many channels are in a category with discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Is there a way how I can show how many channels are in a category with discord.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually a reasonably easy way of doing this. You can fetch all the channels from a guild and then loop through them. You then pick out all the channels which are of type `category` and get the size of their `children` property.

Below is some code which will help you go in the right direction.

```js
client.on("message", async message =>
{
    // Do all your validation and whatnot here
    ....

    const guild = message.guild;

    const categoryChannels = guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === "category");

    categoryChannels.forEach(channel => {
        console.log(`Category ${channel.name} has ${channel.children.size} channels`);
    });
});
```

Give it a try and let me know how it goes!