# How i can get list channels of category

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

how I can get list channel of category. I have already id of this category in categorylist.json. I know how I can get list channels of GUILD, but I dont know how I can get list channels of category

My try:

```
    if (newState && newState.channelID) {
        ChannelJoin(newState.member, newState.CreatorCategory.channels.resolve(newState.channelID));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454263/show-how-many-channels-are-in-a-category-with-discord-js) question, I believe, answers it. The key part is this:

```
const categoryChannels = guild.channels.filter(channel => channel.type === "category");
categoryChannels.forEach(channel => {
    console.log(`Category ${channel.name} has ${channel.children.size} channels`);
});
```

Each object in `categoryChannels` should have property `children`, which you can do whatever you want with.

[Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/CategoryChannel) is the documentation for CategoryChannels.